# using file onchange submit to trigger AJAX file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

My first post here, I've had a couple of days of searching for a solution to my current predicament. I'm sure there are other more experienced coders on here than myself, hence why I am here asking this question now!

I am new to trying javascript, JQuery and AJAX but I would love to be able to learn more about it. I have years of self taught experience of PHP and MySQL, but always shied away from javascript etc.

I'm currently working on a hobby project making my own CMS using PHP.

The issue i'm having is that i'm working on an upload form that works fine and I get the result i'm after if i use the manual Submit button. However I want to hide the horrible looking input file object and use a label instead. I have the label working, however, when I then click open the AJAX isn't triggering.

I'm a total newbie to AJAX, jquery and javascript. I used to avoid it at all costs but I decided I NEED to learn it to be able to stay up to date.

Here's my script most of which has been sourced from the web.

```js
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $('#imageupload').on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         url: \"upload.php\",
   type: \"POST\",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
   success: function(data)
      {
   $(\"#targetLayer\").html(data);
      },
     error: function() 
      {
      }          
    });
 }));
});
</script>
```

```css
.image-upload
{   
    background-color: #eee;
    min-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
.image-upload img
{
    padding: 5px;
}
label {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class='image-upload'><div id='targetLayer'></div><label for='upload-photo'><img src='upload.png'></label></td>
    </tr>
</table></form>
<!-- Image upload form -->
      <!-- removed action='upload.php' as it is referenced in the AJAX code -->
    <form method='post' id='imageupload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <table class='cards-table'>
        <tr>
        <td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$next_id\">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type='file' name='file' id='upload-photo' onchange='submit()'>
        <input type='submit' value='Upload'>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!